# Как восстановить пароль к бд в формате .FDB

Tags: база-данных, firebird

Имеется локально программа, в ней есть бд в формате `.FDB` и скорее всего, она под паролем. Т.к ни одна программа и скрипт не могут сделать коннект, могу ли я как-то сбросить или подобрать его?

Comment: По умолчанию `sysdba:masterkey`

Comment: Попробуйте открыть с помощью `Firebird Embedded Server`

Answer (score 1):

Если Firebird версии меньше 3.0, то сама база точно не запаролена. Список пользователей и пароли хранятся на сервере. Самый простой способ - перенести базу на другой сервер, где пароль известен.